# What sort of "food" did the midwives provide for the children (Rashi on Shemos 1 (17))?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, food, rashi, parashas-shemos, baby-infant

[Rashi on Shemos 1 (17)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9862#showrashi=true&v=17) comments on the expression “... but they enabled the boys to live” and says “They provided water and food for them.”

If these were new-borns what sort of food could they have provided?

We see later that the infant Moshe [Shemos 2 (7)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9863#v=7) used a wet-nurse, not food.

Comment: Also, assuming that it's distinct from simply not killing the babies (as that would perhaps be redundant with "they did not do as the king of Egypt had spoken to them," why not just interpret it to mean that they provided, generally, the care that babies need in order to survive?

Comment: the rashi on Sotah 11b (which is the source for the Rashi on the pasuk) is a bit blurry on the e-daf page but it seems to say that the midwives would keep the boys in their houses and actually raise them, so the food would be sustenance for a while. If anyone can read a clearer printing of the Rashi (I don't have time right now), that would make for a good answer.

Comment: @Danno: http://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Sotah.11b.51?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all

Comment: Egypt had a vast supply of fish, garlics, melons, leeks and cucumbers, as derived from parshat *Beha'alotcha*. They could have eaten any combination of these.

Comment: @IsaacMoses and Danno - so did the midwives keep the children alive **before they were weaned** and if so, how?

Comment: @DanF The unweaned children would eat "fish, garlics, melons, leeks and cucumbers"??

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I know that sounds bizarre to us in today's baby feeding society. But, again, we feed babies strained vegetables at a young age, anyway. What's to cancel the idea that they fed those babies strained cukes and garlic? They're both quite healthy. I don't have any babies to feed, now, but, if you wish, I can ask a pediatrician if this would be problematic.

Comment: @DanF What a good idea. Yes please. I seem to remember a case where a mother made a dilute meat soup (which was clear) to feed her infant in the absence of other arrangements to feed the child.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok FWIW, when my kids were infants we fed them chulent on Shabbat. No meat in it (we don't eat meaty chulent), but it had plenty of garlic cloves in it. The only negative effects it had was that as adults they like garlic a bit too much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33532/discussion-between-danf-and-avrohom-yitzchok).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *braitta* (Sotah 11b) is suggesting that they provided for them even beyond their initial infancy, to the point where they could be self-sufficient (i.e. "וַתְּחַיֶּיןָ" suggests that "they enabled the boys to live").

Possibly, at that stage of the anti-Hebrew decrees, Pharaoh was only requiring feticide or partial-birth abortion, not outright infanticide (Exodus 1:16: 'And he said, "When you deliver the Hebrew women, and you see ***on the birthstool***, if it is a son, you shall put him to death, but if it is a daughter, she may live."'). So once the infants were fully born, the mothers would be able to nurse them. The chiddush of the *braitta* is that they provided for them even beyond that point, when their care might have otherwise been prohibitively expensive for the Hebrew slaves.

[Rashi ad loc](http://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Sotah.11b.51?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) (hattips @Danno and @IsaacMoses):

> ***ותחיין*** - הוה ליה למיכתב ולא המיתו הילדים. ותחיין משמע שהיו מסייעין להחיותן שהיו טומנות אותן בבתיהן ומגדלות אותם:
>
> ***and they enabled the boys to live*** - He should have written "and they did not kill the children". "and they enabled the boys to live" implies that they helped keep them alive - that they hid them in their houses and raised them.

(A counterpoint: The fact that Rashi says "they hid them" suggests that this was also illegal at least by then. If that is the case, there's still no reason to assume that they could not have smuggled in the infants' mothers to nurse them or provided a wet-nurse by other means. The chiddush of the *braissa* is that they indeed went even beyond that.)

Comment: and what nourishment did the children have in their initial infancy?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok while it isn't optimal, cows' milk is often fed to babies. One would imagine sheeps' milk would be available as well. Also, women who gave birth would still be available to sneak over and nurse the babies. (just realized - is your argument that a liquid diet is "drink" and not "food"?)

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok "once the infants were fully born, the mothers would be able to nurse them" (a quotation from this answer)

Comment: @Loewian I am rightly rebuked by msh210. Forget my question about initial infancy.

Comment: The idea of "feticide or partial-birth abortion, not outright infanticide" is supported by the [Ohr Hachaim ad loc](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01609.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2) "כי קודם שיוודע הנולד מה הוא אם בן אם בת יראו המילדות על האבנים אם בן הוא ימיתוהו ויאמרו נולד מת ולא יניחו עד שיצא "